# Laravel 5: Mail::to() ends with PHP Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I've a HTTP Request, which is used by the following function:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
   ...
   $UserRegistration->sendEmail($request);
   ...
}
```

This function calls the function to send an email using the data of the `$request`.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail; // included above class line

public function sendEmail($request = NULL)
{
    $data = $this->subject('Your Registration')
        ->view('emails.user.registration')
        ->text('emails.user.registration_plain')
            ->attach('/files/some_file.pdf', [
                'as' => 'some_file.pdf',
                'mime' => 'application/pdf',
            ])
            ->attach('files/another_file.pdf', [
                'as' => 'another_file.pdf',
                'mime' => 'application/pdf',
            ])
                ->with([
                    'email' => $request['email'],
                    'language' => $request['language'],
                    'registration_token' => $request['registration_token'],
                ]);

    Mail::to($request['email'])->send($data);

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Request completed']);
}
```

Unfortunately fails the line with `Mail:to()` with a HTTP 500 error:

```
2017/01/13 18:29:15 [error] 1484#1484: *102 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting! in /home/vagrant/user-mgmt/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php on line 475
PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/user-mgmt/laravel/public/index.php:0
PHP message: PHP   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle() /home/vagrant/user-mgmt/laravel/public/index.php:53
PHP message: PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() /home/vagrant/user-mgmt/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:117
PHP message: PHP   4. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then() /home/vagrant/user-mgmt/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:150
PHP message: PHP   5. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() /home/vagrant/user-mgmt/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:104
PHP message: PHP   6. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() /home/vagrant/user-mgmt/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:33
PHP message: PHP   7. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle() /home/vagrant/user-mgmt/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:137
PHP message: PHP   8. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() /home/vagrant/user-mgmt/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:46
PHP message: PHP   9. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}() /home/vagrant/user-mgmt/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  10. Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch() /home/vagrant/user-mgmt/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illumi
.
. // Another PHP messages until 'PHP message: PHP 510'
.
```

I've no clue, what is causing this, because `var_dump($request)` returns a very small object, which only contains a maximum of 10 POST based inputs. When I comment out this `Mail:to()` line, the application doesn't throw any error and just works - sure, it doesn't send an email.

Well... I've just read this discussion, but it didn't even fix my problem, when I use a very high value like 2000: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-aborting

How can I solve this issue? Did I something wrong?

Comment: Have you got xdebug by any chance?

Comment: Oh, you've tried 2000. Have you restarted apache / fpm (if you use it)?

Comment: @Farkie yes, I'd restarted the webserver.